# How to make a parbox with rubber width (like \hfill)

Tags: width, parbox, rubber

I have two parboxes that live next to each other:

```
\parbox[t]{2cm}{Foo!}
\hspace{3em}
\parbox[t]{12cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer 
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, 
adipiscing,felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}
```

This works nicely, but I would like to have the second \parbox to have rubber width so it always extends to the right margin. Much like I can do with \hrulefill:

```
\parbox[t]{2cm}{Foo!}
\hspace{3em}
\hrulefill
```

As expected, the rule extends to the right margin.

So I tried to use \fill for the width parameter of the \parbox but that resulted in each word on its own line plus plenty of overfull hbox messages – I assume the width was actually set to 0pt.

Of course, I can play around and come up with a good value for width but that would break as soon as I change the paper format or need a larger \hspace or ...

I also tried a fixed width for the \parbox and \hfill instead of \hspace but again, this breaks/looks ugly when the paper format changes too much.

I'd appreciate any hints and pointers to how to solve this elegantly.

Comment: Place a `\noindent` before the 1st `\parbox`, and *select* the width of the 2nd `\parbox` to be `\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-3em\relax`.  This isn't a rubber width; however, knowing what comes before it, the 2nd box can always be *calculated* to extend to the right margin.  Further, you can also store the box-1 width and the middle gap width in macros, so that things auto-solve themselves even as you reset the left-box size and gap size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion of my original comment...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand\boxAwd{2cm}
\newcommand\midgap{3em}
\newcommand\boxBwd{\dimexpr\linewidth-\boxAwd-\midgap\relax}
\newcommand\boxAB[2]{\noindent\parbox[t]{\boxAwd}{#1\strut}%
  \hspace{\midgap}%
  \parbox[t]{\boxBwd}{#2\strut}}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\boxAB{Foo!}{\lipsum[2]}

\renewcommand\midgap{4em}
\boxAB{I pity the Foo!}{\lipsum[2]}
\end{document}
```

[image]